# Move cursor to the first character after reaching end the last character in textbox

Tags: vb.net

i Have a textbox with a max character length 3 digit and i want user to be able to input the number in a way that the cursor will move back to first character after they finish typing 3 digit. 
For example:
000 -- default value 
100 -- 1st digit input
120 -- 2nd digit input
123 -- 3rd digit input
---And after this, when the user type a new number 4, the string would be
423

any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the MaxLength property of the textbox is set to 3. Declare a global variable 'index'. And add this code to the KeyPress event of the textbox.

To explain my algorithm: you have to make sure that the key pressed is a digit or a letter. To keep track of the index, you increment it by one everytime you press a digit/letter key. If your index exceeded 2, that means you have to reset back to 0.

```
If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        Dim str As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim count As Integer = str.Length

        If count = 3 Then
            Select Case index
                Case 0
                    Dim substr As String = str.Substring(1)
                    Dim newstr As String = e.KeyChar & substr
                    TextBox1.Text = newstr
                    index = index + 1
                Case 1
                    Dim substr As String = str.Substring(0, 1)
                    Dim substr2 As String = str.Substring(2, 1)
                    Dim newstr As String = substr & e.KeyChar & substr2
                    TextBox1.Text = newstr
                    index = index + 1
                Case 2
                    Dim substr As String = str.Substring(0, 2)
                    Dim newstr As String = substr & e.KeyChar
                    TextBox1.Text = newstr
                    index = index + 1
                Case Else
                    index = 0
                    Dim substr As String = str.Substring(1)
                    Dim newstr As String = e.KeyChar & substr
                    TextBox1.Text = newstr
                    index = index + 1
            End Select

        Else
            index = 0
        End If
    End If
```